# Azure Cost Management API - Looking to Connect the Usage API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, azure-app-configuration, azure-cost-calculation

So I'm using Power Automate to connect the API for Azure Cost Management Usage Specifically this guy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list?tabs=HTTP

However, Powerautoamte, though it has an ADAuth with Oauth2 option, requires something called an "Audience?" and really I have no idea what to put here.

I have indeed registered an app, gave it the user-impresonation permission, approved it for my domain, and generated a client/secret for that app. All I need is the "Audience"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Audience` is the API which your AAD app has permissions on.

To find this URL, try to navigate to `Azure AD` and `App Registration`, then select your Application, and click on `API Permissions`.

Select API / Permissions name which should popup the permission details along with the used API.

For example my AAD app has Microsoft Graph permissions

[image]

If I select `Microsoft Graph` row or click on one of the permissions the popup shows details

[image]

[image]

The URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/` represents the Audience in my case.

You are probably using Azure Service Management, so in your case **the Audience** will be `https://management.azure.com/`

[image]